# Programming a basic in-application memory profiling: how to count pointers that are created?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, profiling, wrapper

I have an application in C++ for which I want to implement basic memory profiling capabilities.

For the most important and memory consuming classes, I included in the constructors, copy constructors and destructors, some code that calculates and saves the amount of memory used by each instance of the class (the code runs only when a macro #MEMPROFILE is defined. Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(){
        #ifdef MEMPROFILE
        calcAndSaveMemUsage();
        #endif
    }
...
}
```

Analogously, the destructor updates the counters accordingly. That way, whenever the macro for profiling is defined and a new instance is created like `MyClass obj`, memory consumption info is automatically processed.

Are there ways to automatically do a similar thing to pointers - either in general, or the pointers of that particular class? For intance, to automatically increase a counter every time a pointer is created?

I would be interested in learning more about any ways to achieve that, be it with overloading, wrapping or instrumentation.

PS: I know external tools that would help me profile memory. I am interested in learning that particular thing asked above.

Comment: How about overloading the `new` and `new[]` operators?

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but you could use `std::shared_ptr` and then use its `use_count()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Pointers are not user-defined types. Also, they can be copied by `memcpy` which means the compiler might not even know it's copying them. Behind the scenes, `std::copy` may also use `memcpy` where possible, so it's not just explicit calls to `memcpy` which would trip you up.

Comment: In that case, what about a different approach: instead of wrapping classes or objects, what about overriding `memcpy`, `malloc` and or using what seems to be called [allocation hook functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy8c7wz5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: @Louis15: `memcpy` copies bytes. Whether those bytes contain 0, 1 or more pointers can't be reliably determined. As for creating pointers, the easiest way if by writing `&object` and that involves no function at all.